# why does this does throw a number format exception

Tags: java, mobile, lwuit, j2mepolish

its basically a button event that does multiplication

```
  mul.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {


                if(Sans == null){
                    temp = text;
                }else {
                    temp = Sans ;
                }
                text = "";

                equal = "mul" ;

                textArea.setText("*");
            }
        });
           this is the action that happens when pressing equal button
                 ans.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                if(equal == "mul"){
                    double a = Double.parseDouble(text);
                    double b = Double.parseDouble(temp);
                    double ans = b*a;
                    String Sans = String.valueOf(ans);
                    textArea.setText(Sans);
                    text = "" ;
                }
                    }
```

this code gives the result for the first multiplication but gives a numberformatexception on successive multiplication 
the same code works fine doing a divide operation.

Comment: Bug in your code: Do not use `==` to compare strings. `if(equal == "mul")` is wrong; use `if (equal.equals("mul"))` instead.

Comment: NFE is thrown when you try to parse something that is not a number. If you'll add the full stacktrace we could help you more.

Comment: Do some debugging. Either use your debugger in the IDE and set a breakpoint on the first Double.parseDouble line, or add some System.out.printlns (I think you're interested in the value of text and temp, then you'll see what is wrong).

Comment: If you added the code related to setting the values of `Sans`. `text`, `temp`, that would help as well.

Comment: these are their initial values 

         String text = "0" ;
  String temp = "" ;
  String equal = "";
  String Sans = "";

Answer (score 1):

Update your if condition from

```
if(equal == "mul")
```

to

```
if(equal.equals("mul"))
```

[And learn more about string comparisions. Related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: @AnkurTeotia print the numbers before you assign them to a double. If a number string is not a valid number for example "7s"/"7x" or anything then you will get numberformatexception while doing Double.parseDouble. So make sure your number string is good to be converted to double.